# Is extracting a ISO file to USB the same method as creating a bootable USB?

Tags: usb, iso, extract

I'm trying to create a bootable Ubuntu USB, so that I can boot Ubuntu on my PC. But since I have no other PC left, I'm stuck with just one option. To extract the ISO file directly to the USB using my phone.

I was wondering if this is possible or not. Any ideas on how this would work?

Comment: You want to make bootable USB drive on Android so that makes it an Android question and can be asked at [Android Enthusiast Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is a wonderful question, the op wants to make a Live Ubuntu USB using only his phone, so that he can install Ubuntu on his PC, I totally fail to see how this is off topic.

Comment: @ muru: as it says above "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question."

Comment: How is a question about how to install Ubuntu to USB using Android any different than a question about how to install Ubuntu to USB using Windows or OSX? Are these questions now also going to be banned?

Comment: @AsheDanni Are you trying to create an Ubuntu USB from an Android device, or are you just trying to create *any* bootable USB stick from your Android device?  Clarification is needed here to determine whether or not the post is on topic, given the revision history and the original post does not reference Ubuntu.

Comment: I have re-asked the question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/installing-ubuntu-using-cell-phone-only I have done what I can to ensure it is on-topic

Answer (score 3):

It's possible but not the way you want. Simply extracting the ISO file on USB drive won't make it bootable.

Instead, you can use the app DriveDroid to create the bootable USB. You just need a rooted phone.

[XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2196707) || [Play Store Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid)

Comment: Could tell me more details about this app drivedroid. Why do I need a rooted device. Can't I just extract the files.

Comment: @AsheDanni you can try out the answer below if that doesn't work then you can try the app I provided. to my understanding these ISO's are hybrid ISO and files that are required to make the pendrive bootable aren't injected automatically [See this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2753230/copy-files-iso-image-usb-drive-tool-create-bootable-usb-iso.html)

Comment: @AsheDanni It needs root because it uses features from kernel (as described in play store description), but I do not know much about root so my opinion on the matter is just an opinion.

Comment: DriveDroid sounds too good to be true, I tried it, it's true, +1.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron it has saved me before :)

Comment: Sumeet: I voted DriveDroid the best answer on this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/installing-ubuntu-using-cell-phone-only, Do you really think this thread is off-topic?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Now I'm not sure if it's offtopic or not but I'm pretty sure that It could've easily been asked at [Android Enthusiast](https://android.stackexchange.com/)  , actually a [question already exists](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161036/creating-a-bootable-usb-through-android)

Answer (score 1):

Better to extract an .img to USB than a .iso.
An image file can contain everything a Live or Persistent, (or even a Full), install might need including multiple partitions.

Server is available from Ubuntu as an .img file.

Sudodus has been working with 9w, a minimal OS with mkusb installed.
There are versions based on Ubuntu and on Debian.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/9w#A9w-dus_based_on_Debian_Jessie

Edit: Writing an image file using Android example - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=12098